# Which is the best way to make API call in react web application should i use react fetch or is there available any other best tool

Tags: reactjs

Hi all i wanna make API/Server call for retrieve the data into my react web application how to do that . and which is the best tool for make API call should i use AJAX or react fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React only deals with the view layer, so ideally it is not supposed to make api calls.
Hook react up with other patterns like flux or redux etc and see the magic.

There are couple of other ways to make api calls:

- XMLHttpRequest
- Fetch
- Superagent

I prefer Fetch as it is designed to be more [extensible and efficient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Basic_concepts)

Also, you can see the comparison table below for more options:
https://npmcompare.com/compare/axios,isomorphic-fetch,mappersmith,superagent-bluebird-promise,then-request.

#### Updated on 13 Feb 17:

@Ramusesan : Below is my working code.

**dataAction.js**

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';

export function loadData(data) {
  return {type: types.LOAD_DATA, data};
}

export function getDataById(id) {
  return {type: types.GET_DATA_BY_ID, id};
}

export function loadCompleteData() {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    return fetch("localhost:9090/data/", {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then ((response) => {
            dispatch(loadProfiles(response));
          })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

**configure-store.js**

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState);
    return store;
}
```

Comment: yup i  am using REDUX+REACT since can i use fetch.?

Comment: Yeah you can. in Actions you can make fetch calls. Since you are using redux, I would encourage to use redux-thunk.

Comment: `function loadData(data) {return {type: 'LOAD_DATA', data};}
function loadCompleteData() {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    return fetch("localhost:9090/data/", {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }}).then(response => response.json())
    .then ((response) => {
            dispatch(loadProfiles(response));
          }).catch(error => console.log(error));}}`

Comment: can u tell me how to install fetch api with npm

Comment: No need to install it should be there in Window scope so just call function `fetch`. As per fetch documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API: "For making a request and fetching a resource, use the GlobalFetch.fetch method. It is implemented in multiple interfaces, specifically Window and WorkerGlobalScope. This makes it available in pretty much any context you might want to fetch resources in."

Comment: but here they have given npm install  https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch  i followed  the link which u have mentioned above

Comment: Repo isomorphic-fetch is very old last commit done on that is on May 2016. I am NOT using it in my project. As per MDN link fetch is integrated in Window scope, so this means you should be able to directly call it. I have copy pasted my code in above comment but the code is looking messy in comments. Let me try to copy paste code as separate Answer to the question.

Comment: ok brijesh its great help thank you so much for your valuable and quick reply

Comment: No problem Ram, happy to help. :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no specific way in react, you free to choose.

I would recommend [Fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), it works beautifully. So if you are familiar with ES6 promises etc then go for it.

Your other options are [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)